# How do I get the usersecrets file to load when running a console app from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net-core

This must be a stupid questions..

In my `launchsettings.json` I have tried

```
"environmentVariables": {
      "environment": "Development",
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
      "NETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
}
```

And when I look at the "environment provider" these values exists in the environment.

Trying to use the `UserSecrets` feature, but the docs says that this file will only be added if the environment is set to `Development`.

And looking at the

```cs
HostBuilderContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName
```

It says "Production".. where can I set this value.......argh.. :(

I'm not able to find any documentation on this. But probably I'm missing something simple.

Some more info

Program.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;

namespace TestEnv
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var builder = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();


        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>

           Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureServices((HostBuilderContext, services) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(HostBuilderContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName);

            });
    }
}
```

launchsettngs.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "TestEnv": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output 
`HostBuilderContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName` is `Production`

launchsettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "TestEnv": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "environment=Development",
      "environmentVariables": {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output 
`HostBuilderContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName` is `Development`

And the UserSecrets file is loaded.

Comment: Can you add links or references you have walked through? It will get much clear.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows

Comment: Seems that if i pass inn "environment=Development" as a command line parameter it gets set.  Not able to find that in any documentation....

Answer (score 1):

The structure of a `launchSettings.json`:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "My.ConsoleApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or in Visual Studio right click on your project (not solution) and choose properties. From left menu pick Debug and then you also can write the Environment variables.

Comment: My launchsettings look like that.. Just showed the "interesting" part :D

Comment: do you see the same environment variable within VS as i described?

Comment: Yes, and looking into the "configuration" providers I can see that the variables are there. 
But for some reason they are not "read" by the config builder. Leading to the usersecrets file not being loaded.

Comment: Dont you need the `AddUserSecrets` in the ConfigurationBuilder ?

Comment: Nope that is on by default..It works when I add environment=Deveplopmenmt as paramenter to the command linet

Comment: According to docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows it is only default on AspNetCore. So i think you have to call it explicitly .